# Reading a text from jtextfield by clicking a button in java

Tags: java, jquery

I want to update a database by clicking a buttons. The where clause is getting its item from a textfield, so some button read the text in the text field and some not. I don't know why.

I want to change a date coulmn in a table in the database when the buttons are clicked, so i tried this code

```
 private void jButton34ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    DeleteDate(jTextField6, jTextField5);
}
```

And here is the DeleteDate method

```
 public void DeleteDate (JTextField txt1, JTextField txt2)
{
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String m = "IMCDietitian";
        String unicode= "?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+m+""+unicode+"","root","");
        System.out.println("connected");
        String dept = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        System.out.println(dept);
        System.out.println(txt1.getText());
        System.out.println(txt2.getText());
        System.out.println(jTextField1.getText());

        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate("UPDATE "+dept+" SET edate = '"+jTextField1.getText()+"' WHERE pname = '"+txt1.getText()+"' AND rno = '"+txt2.getText()+"' AND edate = '-'");
        /* This Comment to check the update statement 
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+dept+" WHERE pname = '"+txt1.getText()+"' AND rno = '"+txt2.getText()+"' AND edate = '-'");
        while (rs.next()){
            System.out.println(dept);
            for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(i));
            }
        }

         */
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

so i want to know, why some buttons don't get the text from the textfield?

Thanks all.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Are you sure that the function is actually called from each of the buttons? Is it possible you didn't assign the click event to some of them?

Comment: Did you try to use the debugger ? Are you sure the textField contain values ?

Comment: Thanks all. i determine the problem, i have delete the text before updating the database. Again thanks and sorry for wasting your time.